# javafx diffrent ComboBoxTableCell for every row in a column

Tags: javafx, tableview

I am trying to convert a swing gui to javafx and run into a problem.

I have a jtable (tobe converted to tableview) that contains a nr of columns that have a combobox as "DefaultCellEditor". The combobox Values (String[]) are set dynamically depending on the row index of the jtable.

Or in other words the table has a column in which every row has a combobox with diffrent content.

Now I know e.g. how i can set the same combobox as editor for every cell in a column, but (apperently) no idea on how to put diffrent content in those comboboxes depending on row_index.

In swing i create my table like this:

```
jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable(model)
{
//  Determine editor to be used by row
public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
{
    int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );
    if (Data_Source.ReturnCellEditor(row, column)!=null){
        return Data_Source.ReturnCellEditor(row, column);
    }
    else{
        return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
    }
}
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex == 0)
    return Boolean.class;
    return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
}
```

And from their i have a Method that just returns e.g. combobox-Object (Cast to DefaultCellEditor) dependend on row and column id.

Can anyone help me find a Solution that does something simular in a javafx tableview??

Thank You!

EDIT1:

As for brain's suggestion, I tried my best to make a custom cell factory... but i am still missing something. This way the getIndex() is always -1 ...

```
    public class TestCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>>  {

    public TestCell() {
    }




        @Override
    public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> p) {
        TableCell<S, T> cell = new TableCell<S, T>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                System.out.println("updateItem");

            }
        };
        System.out.println(data.getCoverComboContent(getIndex()));
        return (TableCell<S, T>) new ComboBoxTableCell<>(data.getCoverComboContent(getIndex()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something in javaFX?  I don't think you can get the row using [ComboBoxTableCell](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/ComboBoxTableCell.html), but it should be simple using a custom cell factory.  Just use TableCell.getIndex(), or maybe indexOf() of the underlying table data.  They could be different so I think it would be better to make the combo boxes based on a value stored in the table data.

Comment: I tried a customcell Factory... though likely i am missing something concerning the general logic or so. The only way i could use getIndex() was by extending TableCell. but then the Index is always -1! See edit above.

Comment: Try it in the updateItem() method.  It works fine with my textFields.

Comment: Alternatively, I think you could use TestCell.this.getIndex();

Comment: Yes, with TextFields i got it working as well. But i think the logic is diffrent their because you just use the setValue instead of returning an Object. TestCell.this.getIndex(): Sure that works, but doesnt make a diffrence (Still always -1); (Not sure why it should make a difference though)